# ¿Como asignar diferentes funciones a distintos tipos de usuarios?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando una plataforma de alumnos y maestros, y cada uno tiene diferentes funciones en su perfil.
Cuando se registran, a cada uno en mi base de datos se asigna automáticamente un 1 o un 2, dependiendo de que tipo de usuario es.

> 1 = Maestro
>   2 = Alumno

Y estoy *creando un archivo PHP* que se llama **Perfil.php** donde he estado creando funciones que ambos perfiles ocupan, pero me he topado con funciones exclusivas para maestros.

Pensé en utilizar un query similar a este:

```
 if(DB::query('SELECT TipoUsuario FROM registroalumnos WHERE TipoUsuario = 1'))
```

Gracias.

Comment: Esta bien y dentro de del if poner tu función según el rango.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta es demasiado amplia , indudablemente tendras una tabla que tenga un identificador con su respectiva descripcion para acordarte que es cada cosa , por ejemplo tabla PERMISOS y que tenga 2columnas   , una sera el ID y otra una desc ejemplo ID - 1 , DES - Alumnos , y asi con todo luego solo en tu consulta deberas ir con el identificador de usuario y traerte el tipo de usuario , el where no deberia ser por tipo de usuario ya que aun no sabes , primero con el identificador de usuario encontras al usuario y luego retornas el tipo ,

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es diferenciar usuarios para poder asignarles diferentes niveles de acceso puedes crear una columna llamada "rol" o "nivel" dentro de tu tabla de usuarios, cada numero identificara un rol distinto.

Ej:

> 1 = Maestro 
>   2 = Alumno

Ya teniendo estos datos puedes obtar por un sin numero de opciones distintas, pero te recomiendo que al iniciar sesión almacenes este ID en una variable de sesión

**$_SESSION['nivel'];**

Durante la ejecución de cada script puedes llamar a esta variable y puedes usarla para aplicar filtros sobre el contenido que muestras o las consultas que ejecutes.

Ejemplo:

```
    <?php 
    $nivel=$_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    if($nivel=="1")
    {
    /////aqui puedes poner lo que quieras que solo este nivel ejecute
echo "Eres un maestro";
    }

    if($nivel=="2")
    {
    /////aqui puedes poner lo que quieras que solo este nivel ejecute
echo "Eres un Alumno";
    }
    ?>
```

Suerte, espero haberte ayudado.